# What's the syntax for an AttributeFilter in FME?

Tags: fme-form

I want to use AttributeFilter and I need to filter data by ATTRIBUTE1 with possible values of ATTRIBUTE2. What is the syntax for it?

I tried:

1. attribute2
2. &attribute2
3. $attribute2
4. '&attribute2'

etc. but wasn't successful.

Comment: A screenshot of this part of your workspace would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to add a feature merger for attributes only.

If you could expand on the question can give a better answer.

[image]

Note: Using FME 2012 here

Comment: Can you explain how this would work? I have used FeatureMergers to effectively join attributes from one feature type to another, but in this case there is no "supplier", so what does it do?

Comment: Bravo:) As you said. Both input data sets (xml and gdb) connected to the FatureMerger and than used Tester are solution to get exactly what i need, this specific polygon according to the attribute2 in xml.

Comment: And I forgot to say, I used FeatureMerger FME2011

Comment: I used XML dataset as supplier, and sde dataset as requestor, and outputed through the complete to tester!

Answer (score 4):

The AttributeFilter is when you want to filter by a number of possible values.

If you just want to check whether Attribute1 = Attribute2, then use a Tester transformer.

If you want to check whether Attribute1 = Attribute2, or Attribute3, or Attribute4, etc, then use a TestFilter transformer.

If you want to check whether Attribute 1 = A, or B, or C where these are possible values of Attribute2, then just enter them into the AttributeFilter, or use the Import option.

Comment: Ok. It seems Tester to be a solution, but now i have following problem.
If I use by writing number 610 on the right side in Tester directly like "Attribute1 = 610" than i Visualizer I got exactly this area with ID 610.
And If i try to write "Attribute1 = Attribute2" and Attribute2 has a value which is in XML then I get empty set of data i VIsualizer.
This makes me to the conclusion that data value are not the same, although they are... I do not know, any idea?!

Comment: Solution: FeatureMerger

Answer (score 2):

I think the syntax is:

```
@Value(Attribute2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think that #2 would work, but did you try all caps, as in `&ATTRIBUTE2`? Also, have you tried importing the Possible Attribute Values to see what that might give you:

[image]

Comment: Yes, i know that all. It does not help because in xml file is only one of many possible values for attribute2.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know what AttributeFilter you mean but in "Definiton Query" of ArcGIS it done this way:
"ATTRIBUTE1" = "ATTRIBUTE2"  - this will select all rows whith the same value in both fields

Comment: I am talking about FME. That you wrote above is not working. :( unfortunatly.