# Test Attribute with 1 or more possible values in FME?

Tags: fme-form

This question continues story on link [What's the syntax for an AttributeFilter in FME?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17400/whats-the-syntax-for-an-attributefilter-in-fme).

Now, how can I test attribute value if there are more than one value and proceed it to the Clipper (uses as a multiple clippers)? Use some looping method?

In xml file is for example

So there can be maybe only one or can be many of them.

I tried and Tester output is only one value (last of possible values, in my example above Tester output is only areaID=1253).

Tnx,

Answer (score 1):

Most simple way is do an OR test with your tester.
Set the test criteria to "OR"
And then set a test for each attribute value
For example:
OR
areaID=1253
areaID=1254
areaID=1255
areaID=1304
etc

Comment: This is what I know. I would like to do this without specify a specific value. Let imagine that value can be any number...In that case, how to do what I wanted?

Comment: If you just want to test if it is a number (rather than a string) then the AttributeClassifier might help.

Answer (score 1):

**Composite Tests.** (using the Tester Transformer)

*Up until now, Testers have been resticted to a single test, for example an AND (Clause 1 AND Clause 2) or an OR (Clause 1 OR Clause 2), so that multiple clauses required multiple transformers.*

[image]

Credit to Mark Ireland ([Safe Software](http://safe.com/)) and [GIS SE member](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/users/454/mark-ireland).

Source:
http://evangelism.safe.com/fmeevangelist70/

Comment: I do not get it, unfortunaly. In Tester parameter you have to write exactly how many rtest clauses you r going to have. But what If you do not know If there will be just one value of an atribute or there will be more? In XML file where those value of attribute are, sometimes can be just one, and sometimes can be more ..I hope someone understand what I have to do?! Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I did it. So, attribute with multiple values I have defined as list in xfmap fil. After that by use of ListExploder in front of FeatureMerger, and than FeatureMerger itself connected to Tester I got postiv result as needed. Use of FeatureMerger is neccessry and just than can we perform testing. Why is that, it is still unknown to me?!...But that's solution for what i need. I hope this can help someone.